# How can pass my php session_id() in ajax jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

```
// Show Cart Quantity
function showCartById(){
    var inProcess = false;//Just to make sure that the last ajax call is not in process
    if (inProcess) {
        return false;//Another request is active, decline timer call ...
    }
    inProcess = true;//make it burn ;)
    var sId = $(this).attr('sid');
    var data = 'sId='+sId;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'cart.php', //Define your script url here ...
        data: data, //Pass some data if you need to
        method: 'POST', //Makes sense only if you passing data
        success: function(answer) {
            alert(answer)
            inProcess = false;//Queue is free, guys ;)
        },
        error: function() {
            //unknown error occorupted
            inProcess = false;//Queue is free, guys ;)
        }
    });

}
```

I want to pass my PHP Session_id() with ajax request method. But without Session_id() it works well.

Comment: Are you using load-balanced servers? If not, then the server will already know your session id, and you don't need to pass it

Comment: Try using JSON format at data instead of sId=sId, example ..... { "sId" : sessionId}

Comment: If you wan to send a session value in cart.php, just use session_start() at the top in cart.php and all the session that you have set will be available.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `var session_id = '<?php echo session_id();?>';` and pass it to the data

Comment: `public function getTotalQue($sId){
  $sId  = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $sId);
  $query = "SELECT quantity FROM tbl_cart WHERE  sId = '$sId'";
  $result = $this->db->select($query);
  $qty = 0;
  if ($result) {
    while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $qty = $qty+$data['quantity'];
   }
   echo $qty;
   
  }else{
   echo "0";
  }



  
 }`

Comment: ok, you can do var session_id = '<?php echo $sId;?>'; and pass it to the data parameters

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I have fixed this issue.

Comment: Does it help or you found some different solution?

Comment: Yes, I have used look like in header.`<script type="text/javascript">
        var sId = '<?php echo session_id();?>';
    </script>`